# Capacitor equivalent

Tags: voltage, capacitor, circuit-design, motor-controller

I am unable to find a replacement capacitor for my well pump.......that capacitor is labeled
*Phillips capacitor  3534B5A0088A330A4*
Would someone please direct me to where I can find a cross reference chart for this part?
Thank you!

Comment: Picture of this capacitor needed, please ...

Comment: What country?  Just searching the part number gives me retail hits.

Comment: https://www.westfloridacomponents.com/J563APK02/43uF-53uF+250VAC+Motor+Start+Capacitor++Philips+3535B4A0043A250A5.html

Comment: A 47 uF motor start capacitor?

Comment: Country USA,  yes, motor start

Answer (score 1):

##### TL;DR

You need a *88-108 µF capacitor rated at 330 V*, of EIA Type II.

The capacitor *looks like* this:

[image: 3500 series A.C. motor start capacitor]

---

From the [Series 3500 A.C. Motor Start Capacitor datasheet](https://www.westfloridacomponents.com/mm5/graphics/K02/3535B4A0043A250A5.pdf):

> The last two digits are for internal use only. They are
> sequentially assigned and have NO predetermined meaning.

So your part number is actually `3534B5A0088A330**`

The last three digits (330) are the voltage rating, i.e. 330 V

The numbers between the `A` characters (0088) is the minimum capacitance in µF, i.e. 88-108 µF

`3534` series are "light-duty" EIA Type II (whereas `3535` are EIA Type I).

---

Also from the datasheet:

> [image: Product ID decoder]

Comment: THANK YOU!   Country USA  First time user here, getting acquainted with forum.  Thanks for the patience

Comment: Please upvote and/or mark the answer as accepted if it helped.